subrings of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, the ring of integers modulo $n$
Define subrings to be subgroups that are closed under multiplication, not necessarily require the identity.
Then are the subrings of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ just the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$? This is my idea:
Since the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ possesses unique subgroups of each order dividing $n$, so the set of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is $\big\{\,d\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\,\big|\,d|n\,\big\}$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\;da_1\,(\mathrm{mod}\ n)\cdot da_2\,(\mathrm{mod}\ n)
 \\=&\;d(da_1a_2)\,(\mathrm{mod}\ n)
 \\\in&\;d\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},
\end{aligned}
$$
so these subgroups are all closed under multiplication, hence are subrings.

"Then if the subrings of $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ are just the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}(n)$?"... Your "if" is lacking a "then".

Why do you doubt your proof?

Subrings are more commonly called ideals ;)

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@Maxime: No, subrings and ideals are two different things. For an ideal $I$ of a (commutative) ring $A$, we require that for all $x\in I$ and all $y\in A$, $xy\in I$.

My bad, as I never encountered the notion of subrings as described here, I thought that the condition to be closed under multiplication referred to the external multiplication by any element of $\mathbb Z/(n)$.

@ArturoMagidin thanks, I have corrected it.

@anankElpis Since I find no one have discussed this question under this definition of subrings. And I just wish to ensure my thought is right.
